# In Spring data JPA, how can I set the property expressions precedence?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have this JPA query method:
`findByZzzAndXxxOrYyy`

which gives results for:
`findBy(ZzzAndXxx)OrYyy // "And" gets higher precedence`

Can I get results for?
`findByZzzAnd(XxxOrYyy) // "Or" gets higher precedence`

Guess I can do it with other query types (e.g. native)
but I wonder if I could just set the precedence by adding underscores or symbols or something...

Comment: Did you try with findByXxxOrYyyAndZzz()?

Comment: Sorry, no... it results in findByXxxOr(YyyAndZzz)

Comment: Vote for this question

Comment: It's a bit late, but I have the same doubt and no answer yet. The only way I figured out is to repeat params: findByZzzAndXxxOrZzzAndYyy

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood it correctly, You would be writing a query, so you would have to make sure that whatever operation you want to perform first, should be included in parenthesis to get desired result.

E.g. I have table DEMO with Demo being the entity class with fields a,b and c.
So per your requirement, the query would be:

Select * from Demo d where (d.a="SOME_VALUE" or d.b= "SOME_VALUE") and d.c="SOME_VALUE"

Comment: Hi Gourav, if I wanted to create the query in SQL then yes, you are correct. but I want to use "Spring JPA method query" which allows to write queries using the method name itself. it's a bit different :)